# Trigger mysql - error?

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Olá, é a primeira vez que estou a usar triggers e não sei como resolver um erro que estou a ter e um problema que nao sei como fazer.

Eu quero fazer um trigger para quando uma data inserida  (data inicio e fim) estiver sobreposta entre uma data que já exista.. isto é, se uma data A a  D  já existir, não pode ser inserida uma data B a C.. ou C a E porque ficam sobrepostas..

O meu SELECT já está correcto penso eu, no entanto eu não sei como fazer isso dar erro caso as datas sejam sobrepostas.. já tentei com raise error e outras maneiras mas dá me sempre erro de sintax..

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tri_check_date_overlap BEFORE INSERT ON Oferta
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN


    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM Oferta WHERE 
             (new.morada = morada AND new.codigo = codigo 
                AND ((new.data_inicio BETWEEN data_inicio AND data_fim) OR new.data_fim BETWEEN data_inicio AND data_fim)
             )
             )


            /*CALL raise_application_error(3001, 'erro!'); */
            DECLARE msg varchar(255); 
            set msg = concat('Error: overlaping dates!', cast(new.right as char));
            signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;




END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

O que tenho de corrigir?

Comment: Qual a versão do MySQL? Que acho que só funciona no 5.5

Comment: 5.1.73.. N sei se será disso.. Eu estava a pensar que seria algo a ver com o THEN.. Talvez um END IF.. Pq é erro de sintaxe..Mas sinceramente nao sei

Comment: Coloca o erro que tá dando na pergunta